# If $R$ has more than one element, does $R/N$ has more than one element?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $N$ be an ideal of a ring $R$. Then the additive cosets of $N$ form a the quotient ring $R/N$. Is it true that if $R$ has more than one element that $R/N$ has more than one element? If not, it is true if $R$ has identity $1 \neq0$?

Comment: consider the case $N=R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is unital and take the unit ideal $(1)=R$. Then $R/R$ is a singleton, and so $1= 0$.

The same example works in the nonunital case, too.

Comment: What is meant by unital?

Comment: A ring is unital if it has $1$.

Comment: Are there counterexamples if we require that $N\neq R$?

Comment: Well... no. If $N\ne R$, then there are at least 2 cosets.

Comment: Could you please explain how do you conclude this?

Comment: Sure. If $x\in R$ but $x\not \in N$, then the cosets $x+N$ and $N$ are distinct. Indeed, $x+N=N$ if and only if $x\in N$, which it is not by construction.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still a little bit uncomfortable concluding "If x∈R but x∉N, then the cosets x+N and N are distinct." It seems obvious, but is there any reason you might be able to provide as to why this is true?

Comment: You should revise the definition of equality of cosets.